# How to add style on html tag on android

Tags: android

heres my code:

```
String tempStr = "The <b>quick</b> brown fox";
tvView.setText(Html.fromHtml(tempStr), BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

What i want is to add a color to the  tag. Tnx in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Hi you can use like this. you can set any style which is use in css:

String html = "<html><head><title></title> "
            + "<style type=\"text/css\"> "
            + "body {background-image:url('file:///android_res/drawable/background.png'); background-repeat: repeat-y; font-family:"
            + Fontname
            + "; } "
            + "</style> "
            + "</head><body ><div>"
            + "<p><FONT COLOR=\"#f7bd79\" >" + yourstring
            + "</FONT></p></div> </body></html>";
```

Comment: String tempStr = "The <html><head><title></title><style> b{ color: red} </style></head><body><b>quick</b></body></html> brown fox";

Comment: also wont work:

    String tempStr = "The <html><head><title></title></head><body><b color=\"red\">quick</b></body></html> brown fox ...";

tvView.setText(Html.fromHtml(tempStr), BufferType.SPANNABLE);

Comment: hi sory for late rply i was busy with some work.  String tt ="This is a <b><FONT COLOR=\"#f7bd79\" >text</FONT></b>";
        text.setText(Html.fromHtml(tt)); eaisly you can set font color.